# Weblogic console get current password for any user

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c, java-ee-7

I am trying to automate a weblogic password change activity which will take the user and new password for an user, connect weblogic console through admin account and reset the password for the specific user. The requirement is to validate if the password matches with existing password; if so, it will not try to reset the password. I could not find any api in wlst which returns the current password. Can anyone please help in this regard?

Comment: for security reason, such an API does not exist. You can only check that the user can logs in the console.

Comment: you can do the password equality check if you create a new user with the entered old password and check if this stored (encoded) password equals to the password stored for the target user. (and delete the transient user record)